# google gmail api を用いてメールの本文を取得する際

Tags: python, api, gmail

gmail apiを用いて本文の取得を試みましたが、utf-8形式？のままで出力されてしまいます。日本語で読めるようにしたい場合、utf-8でデコードすればよろしいのでしょうか？

```
`print(msg['payload'])`：
`{'partId': '', 'mimeType': 'text/html', 'filename': '',
'headers': [{'name': 'Received', 'value': 'from 303582994364 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Wed, 6 Feb 2019 15:45:52 -0800'}, {'name': 'Date', 'value': 'Wed, 6 Feb 2019 15:45:52 -0800'},{'name': 'From', 'value':  <xxx@gmail.com>'},{'name': 'Reply-To', 'value': '"XXX" <YYYY@gmail.com>'}, {'name': 'Message-Id','value':'<MMMM@mail.gmail.com>'}, {'name': 'X-Mailer', 'value': 'WPMailSMTP/Mailer/gmail 1.3.3'},{'name': 'MIME-Version', 'value': '1.0'}, {'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}, {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value': '8bit'},{'name':'To','value':'XXXXXX@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Subject', 'value': "XXXXX"], 'body': {'size': 8103, 'data': jabisyfusag....}}`
```

最後の'body':の'data'の部分が本文だと思いますが、日本語に変換できません。ご教授ください。
`print(mainmsg['body']['data'])`で本文出力は確認済みです。デコードを試みましたが、`.decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')`エラーが返ってきます。AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドキュメントによれば**base64**でエンコードされた文字列のようです。

[Users.messages.attachments | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments?hl=ja#resource)

> The body data of a MIME message part as a base64url encoded string.

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。charset=UTF-8とあったので誤解していました。base64.urlsafe_b64decodeでデコードしたところ、 `b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="ja">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<title>\xe3\x81\xb6\xe3\x81\x</title>\n</head>\n<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">\n\t\t<.... `のような形で出力されました。調べてみます。